# Tensorflow: how do I extract/export variable values at every iteration of training?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I have been playing around with some neural networks on Tensorflow and I wanted to make a visualization of the neural network's learning process. 
To do so, I intend to extract the following variables into text/JSON/csv: pre-activation result before 1st layer, activation, bias and weight values for testing and training, each layer and for all time steps. I am looking for a generalizable solution so that I don't have to modify my source code (or at least not more than one or two lines) when applying visualization to future networks. Ideally I could run some function from another python program to read any python/TF code and extract the variables described above. So far I have considered the following solutions:
1) use tf.summary and the filewriter to save as a serialized protocol buffer, then find a way to go from protocol buffer --> JSON format. This unfortunately would not fit the bill as it requires me to modify too much inner code. 
2) Perhaps using https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/export_meta_graph
Although I am not sure how to implement given my TF foundations are not quite there yet
3) I have also found this solution:

```
W_val, b_val= sess.run([W, b])
np.savetxt("W1.csv", W_val, delimiter=",")
np.savetxt("b1.csv", b_val, delimiter=",")
```

But the problem is that it only saves the final values of the weights and biases, whereas I am looking to save their values at all timesteps of training.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to tackle this problem or any guidance I would appreciate it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doing it with `tf.Summaries` is probably a good idea. You could then visualize it all in Tesnorboard, much like with some of the tutorials and the inception retraining code.
Alternatively you could perform fetches within your `sess.run()` call to grab whatever tensors you like at every step (i.e. every run call).

I have pasted a response to a similar question regarding extracting the cross entropy from another question below:
When you do your session run call (e.g. `res = sess.run(...)` ) then you can put in a fetch for your cross entropy variable.

For example, let's say you have a complicated `sess.run()` call that gets some predictions but you also want to your cross entropy then you may have code that looks like this:

```
feeds={x_data:x,y_data:y}
fetches=[y_result,cross_entropy]
res=sess.run(fetches=fetches, feed_dict=feeds) predictions=res[0]
#your first fetch parameter xent=res[1] #Your second fetch parameter.
```

Fetches within the run call allows you to "fetch" tensors from your graph.

You should be able to do the above but instead of cross entropy, just a list of whatever you want. I use it to fetch both my summaries and also intermediate accuracy values.

Comment: Hey JCooke,

Thanks a bunch for the helpful answer. So I ended up managing to implement it using fetch, yey! I still have a lingering question though: 
It worked using only res=sess.run(fetches=fetches) within my training loop. So what would be the difference to use res=sess.run(fetches=fetches, feed_dict=feeds) instead as indicated in the sample code you gave above? I guess the x and y data are both taken into account somehow but would this output be the same as the output from res=sess.run(fetches=fetches)?

Comment: Sure. So sess.run() takes loads of arguments including fetches amd feed_dict. They're called like any other function i.e. `sess.run(fetches=[fetches],feed_dict={feeds})` You use feed_dict to push data into your placeholders if you have them. If you are making a run call with your x,y data already then there is no need to make a separate one to fetch your values, you can just do it in one call! Your fetch array will give you an array in res so res[0]=first fetch value, res[1]=second and so on. Does that help? Can clarify further if required.

Comment: Great that makes sense! Thank you so much. So I noticed the sample code I am using from the TF tutorials has a sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) in the beginning after declaring W and B weights as tf variables. I don't think I want to set a variable equal to that term though because it is not in the training loop so would just give me one "time slice" of weight and bias values (I guess whatever values they are initialised at). So in this particular instance is .run being used in a different way than what we have been discussing above?

Comment: Just to check I am correctly making sense of your answer, since there is already a .run in my training loop:
train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
And I am inserting another .run within my training loops to extract values:
current1, current2 = sess.run([W, b])
What I understand from your comment is that I can combine both, perhaps something like this:
current1, current2 = train_step.run(fetches = [W,b],feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
Does that sound about right?

Comment: Yep that's basically it. Or you can do it in one variable and index by fetch. For full usage instructions with sess.run(), [check out the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run).

Answer (score 0):

```
for step in range(num_train_steps):
    _, weight_values, bias_values = sess.run([your_train_op, weight, bias])
    # save weight_values and bias_values
```